# Cant configure Spring Batch to run a java class ?

Tags: spring-batch

I use the following job launcher to launch my spring batch jobs, i want to run  one class named Notify, how can i configure it ?

this is my job file :

```
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong" />
     <!-- stored job-meta in memory -->
     <bean id="jobRepository"
class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
     </bean>
     <bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />
     <bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
     </bean>
     <bean id="report" class="com.mkyong.model.Report" scope="prototype" />
     <bean id="customWriter" class="com.mkyong.writers.CustomWriter" />
     <bean id="notify" class="com.mkyong.model.Notify" />
      <constructor-arg>
      <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao"/>
      </constructor-arg>
     </bean>
     <bean id="runScheduler" class="com.mkyong.RunScheduler" />

     <!-- Run every 5 seconds -->
     <task:scheduled-tasks>
    <!-- <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run" fixed-delay="5000" 
        /> -->
    <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run"
        cron="*/20 * * * * *" />
     </task:scheduled-tasks>
    </beans>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "run"? The notify class in that xml seems to be part of the model, (just a Java Bean). And that code has been clearly pasted from mkyong.com web page...

Answer (score 0):

where ever you need to call the class you can use auto wiring for this purpose -

Then you can use the instance of the class to call the respective methods fomr the class.

```
@autowire
@qualifier('notify') 
Notify nnotifyObject ;
```